# OAuth implementation with WINUI unpackaged app not working

Tags: oauth, maui, exe, winui-3

In MAUI application, I have implemented OAuth by opening up a browser window and redirecting user back to app once authentication is complete using protocol mentioned in **Package.appxmanifest** file as below:

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
    <uap:Protocol Name="appName">
      <uap:DisplayName>App</uap:DisplayName>
    </uap:Protocol>
  </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

This is working fine with packaged WINUI application. But in unpackaged app version redirection to app is not working. I have implemented oAuth using browser because **WebAuthenticationBroker** is not working in MAUI for WINUI.

Tried with [WinUIEx](https://dotmorten.github.io/WinUIEx/concepts/Maui.html)  package. But it requires packaged application.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid this is still not supported, and MS don't even consider it on their roadmap.  Some info here: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/pull/3202